# Surjective Closed Map from Affine Plane to Affine Line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

I was wondering if there is a way to prove that there does not exist a surjective, closed map $f \colon \mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{A}^1$ where closed is in terms of the Zariski topology. Intuitively, it seems that collapsing a variety in the plane to a line should result in a singularity resulting in some open set somewhere. For example, if we have the natural projection $\pi \colon \mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{A}^1$ then it cannot be universally closed as $Z(xy-1)$ maps to $D(0)$, which is what motivated my intuition.

Comment: Universal closedness is a different property, though. In principle it is possible that there is a closed but not universally closed map.

Comment: The question would be straightforward if the condition was "universally closed": Indeed a universally closed morphism $f\colon\mathbb A^2\to \mathbb A^1$ would be both affine and proper, which means $f$ would be finite. Of course, no such morphism is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that the field is the complex numbers.

Let $ \phi: \mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1 $ be surjective and closed. The map $ \phi $ is given by a nonconstant polynomial $ f = f(x,y) $.

For a general choice of $ g = g(x,y) $ of large enough degree, the polynomial $ h = fg-1 $ is irreducible. ($\bullet $)

Then $ Z = \mathbb{V}(h) $ is an irreducible affine curve, so $ f(Z) $ is irreducible and closed (by assumption), so $ f(Z) $ is either a point or $ \mathbb{A}^1 $. But clearly $ f(Z) $ misses $ 0 $, so $ f(Z) = c $ for some constant $ c $. Then $ f-c $ vanishes on $ Z $, i.e. $ f-c \in I(Z) = (h) $. Writing $ f-c = qh= q(fg-1) $ for some $ q $ gives $ (qg-1)f = q-c $, a contradiction because the degree of $ g $ was assumed large enough.

I only haven't justified $ (\bullet) $ fully for lack of time, I'll add it later.

Comment: I'm not sure how the last part is a contradiction, if we increase the degree of $g$ doesn't that change $h$, thus changing $q$ such that $f-c = qh$? Although I feel like there is a contradiction in $f-c = q(fg-1)$ in that if $g$ is nonconstant, there is some nonzero monomial on the RHS that has degree strictly greater than that on the LHS unless $q$ is $0$ and $f$ is $1$, in which case the map is not surjective.

Comment: Sure, $ h , q $ both change but I'm only looking at the equation $ (qg-1)f = q - c $. The highest degree monomials on the RHS are those of $ q $ while on the LHS they're those of $ qgf $ and $ g $ has large degree, so I think my argument isn't essentially wrong?